# cambiar numerico a fecha IREPORT

Tags: java, xml, formato, ireport, reporte

Buen dia:
Tengo un reporte y me tiene un campo $F{MES} de tipo string
quiero que el reporte me diga ese dato pero en TEXTO como MES
Ejemmplo si el dato es 01 el reporte debe mostrar "ENERO"
Adicionalmente copio el extracto de XML que tiene el reporte sobre ese campo en donde se muestra

```
<textField pattern="">
            <reportElement x="190" y="138" width="141" height="15" uuid="a5511515-984d-49c9-9280-d10893190019"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MES}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que agregar una condicion if con el operador ternario, te muestro un ejemplo

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MES} == '01' ? 'ENERO' : $F{MES} == '02' ? 'FEBRERO' : $F{MES} == '03' ? 'MARZO' : null ]]></textFieldExpression>
```

He modificado la respuesta para que tengas mejor idea de como lo puedes hacer con los siguientes meses, asi sucesivamente puedes realizarlo para los restantes, cuando llegues a "Diciembre" tienes que poner un null o '', por esa razon ves el null en el codigo.

Comment: ok, pero para todos los meses podria usar un case, tendrás un ejemplo?

Comment: Ya modifique mi respuesta, me dices si eso te sirve

Comment: correcto tu solución me sirvió